# Web Api routing with parameter option?

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api-routing

I would like to provide a ASP.Net Web API that can be called by the following formats:

> http
>   ://myApiServer/API/MyLookupMethod/GetForIVR/PhoneNumber/8005551212

or

> http
>   ://myApiServer/API/MyLookupMethod/GetForIVR?LookupType=PhoneNumber&LookUpValue=8005551212

Is it possible to set up a route that works with either call?

My current route is

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
name:"MyRoute",
routeTemplate:"api/{controller}/{action}/{Lookuptype}/{lookupvalue}"
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use attribute routing

```
[Route("api/user/YourMethodName/{id}/{param2}")]
[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage YourMethodName(int id = 0, bool param2= true)
```

Hope it works!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Attribute based routing i.e. specific routing on controllers and methods. Further you should pass your 2 parameters as query-string like in this URL MyLookupMethod/GetForIVR?LookupType=PhoneNumber&LookUpValue=8005551212 and they will be automatically parsed as method parameters.

```
public class SomeController : ApiController
{
    // GET MyLookupMethod/GetForIVR?LookupType=PhoneNumber&LookUpValue
    [Route("MyLookupMethod/GetForIVR")]
    public Book Get(int LookupType, int LookUpValue) { ... }

}
```